# SimpleMessageListenerContainer is not recover after stoping it

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

When a certain event arrives, I stop my `rabbitmq listner` using `container.stop();` and after the needed job is done, I restart it with `container.start()`, but when a new event arrives, I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" 2016-04-22T16:20:53.646  WARN 15336 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.isActive(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:756) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1100) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a harmless (but scary) log messsage, but it is [fixed in 1.5.3](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-556).

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332460/spring-rabbitlistner-stop-listening-to-queue-using-annotation-syntax-springra/34336517#34336517):

> It's generally better to stop the container on a separate thread.

because the container can't fully stop until the listener exits.

Comment: See the edit to my answer (I am not sure if SO notifies you of my edits).

Comment: I saw that the error is harmless, because everything works fine.